# ZonedDateTime method withZoneSameInstant always return null when mocked

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using mockito to mock ZonedDateTime.now() in my tests i have a mapper that map a ZonedDateTime to a OffsetDateTime. but when i call zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) the return value is always null (zonedDateTime) is not null.

My mapper (using mapstruct)

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL)
public interface OffsetDateTimeMapper {

    default OffsetDateTime mapZonedDateTimeToOffsetDateTime(@NotNull ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime); // print 2021-03-06T14:05Z[UTC]
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // print null
        return zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime();
    }
}
```

My mock for tests

```java
    @NotNull
    private static MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> getZonedDateTimeMockedStatic(String isoTimeString) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(isoTimeString);

        MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> mockedLocalDateTime = mockStatic(ZonedDateTime.class);
        mockedLocalDateTime.when(() -> ZonedDateTime.now(any(ZoneId.class))).thenReturn(zonedDateTime);
        mockedLocalDateTime
                .when(() -> any(ZonedDateTime.class).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))
                .thenReturn(zonedDateTime); // this seems to do nothing
        return mockedLocalDateTime;
    }
```

a test method

```java
    @Test
    void should_return_empty() {
        // given
        ContainerRequest containerRequest = ContainerRequest.builder().containerNumber("TGBU6795701").build();

        // when
        MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> mockedLocalDateTime = getZonedDateTimeMockedStatic("2021-03-01T18:35:24.00Z");
        when(mockContainerDetailsProviderService.getContainerInfos(containerRequest)).thenReturn(
                optionalContainerDetailsResponseFromJson("responses/EmptyContainerDetails.json"));
        Optional<ContainerEtaResponseDto> result = etaService.getEtaByContainer("TGBU6795701");
        mockedLocalDateTime.close();

        // then
        assertTrue(result.isEmpty());
    }
```

If i change my
return zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toOffsetDateTime();
to
return zonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime();
It work well but it seems to be not the correct way to convert a ZonedDateTime to a OffsetDateTime

I think my mock is the problem but i cant find a way to make it works.

EDIT:
It work by using CALL_REALS_MAETHODS as mock parameters

```java
    @NotNull
    private static MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> getZonedDateTimeMockedStatic(String isoTimeString) {
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(isoTimeString);

        MockedStatic<ZonedDateTime> mockedLocalDateTime = mockStatic(ZonedDateTime.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
        mockedLocalDateTime.when(() -> ZonedDateTime.now(any(ZoneId.class))).thenReturn(zonedDateTime);
        return mockedLocalDateTime;
    }
```

Comment: Your mock of the returned time looks weird to me, have you tried `when(mockedLocalDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(any())).thenReturn(zonedDateTime)`?

Comment: yes the way i have done it was wrong
But i've got my problem resolved by using CALL_REALS_MAETHODS as mock parameters (see edit below)